# Sort Multidimensional Array by stock

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I trying to sort the following array by STOCK:

Lines to process:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [SKU] => 3
            [NAME] =>
            [STOCK] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [SKU] => 020714297909
            [NAME] =>
            [STOCK] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [SKU] => 020714305383
            [NAME] =>
            [STOCK] => 2
        )

)
```

can u help me?

Regards

Comment: Use `usort()` with a comparison function that compares `STOCK`.

Comment: Try this one liner: array_multisort( array_column($yourArray, "STOCK"), SORT_ASC, $yourArray);